# Can somebody explain the tr /d modifier in perl?

Tags: perl, tr

I found this example in a Perl tutorial, but could not understand the output. The tutorial says:

> The /d modifier deletes the characters matching SEARCHLIST that do not have a corresponding entry in REPLACEMENTLIST.

but I could not figure out how this is realized in the example.

Can somebody explain how the output was generated?

Script:

```
$string = 'the cat sat on the mat.';
$string =~ tr/a-z/b/d;
print "[$string]\n";
```

Output:

```
[ b b   b.]
```

(The square brackets mark the start and end of the string, that's all.)

Comment: That's a [transliteration](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators), it has nothing to do with regex ;)

Comment: How odd - the duplicate question uses the very same example text.

Answer (score 10):

Since there is only one character in the replacement list (`b`), only the first character in the searchlist (`a`) will be replaced with `b`. The rest of characters in the search list (`b-z`) will be deleted.

Hence, replacing `a`s with `b`s and `b-z` letters with nothing,

> the c**a**t s**a**t on the m**a**t.

becomes  `b b   b.` (there are only three `a`s in the sentence and the spaces and the dot are preserved as they were not part of the searchlist).

Comment: Very clear. Thanks a lot. By the way, does anybody know why my question got a -1 from SO? Is it due to the inappropriate label "regex"? (If it is, sorry about that.)

Comment: @leo, the -1 is from a person and not SO itself. Either they didn't like that they got baited with the `regex` tag, or they didn't like how your initial version was formatted or they thought that you didn't put enough effort do understand this yourself before asking.